# cache sprites to save the memory

Tags: caching, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

in my games scene i use 5 background images(sprites) in CCParallaxNode and I have to use each sprite twice to move all this layers permanently. How can I cache this sprites to save the memory?

I just want escape from **CCSprite *for _level_1** and **CCSprite *for _level_2** cuz it the same image twice.

```
_backgroundNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
_backgroundNode.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
_backgroundNode.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[self addChild:_backgroundNode z:-1];
```

.....

in loop

```
            CCSprite *fon_level_1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name]];
            CCSprite *fon_level_2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name]];
            fon_level_1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
            fon_level_1.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
            fon_level_2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
            fon_level_2.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
            [_backgroundNode addChild:fon_level_1 z:zIndex parallaxRatio:ccp(ratio, ratio) positionOffset:ccp(offsetx, offsety*screenSize.height)];
            [_backgroundNode addChild:fon_level_2 z:zIndex parallaxRatio:ccp(ratio, ratio) positionOffset:ccp(fon_level_1.contentSize.width, offsety*screenSize.height)];
            [_backgrounds addObject:fon_level_1];
            [_backgrounds addObject:fon_level_2];
```

method, where move the fons and check achieving the end of backgrounds layers

```
-(void) updateBackgroud:(ccTime)delta
{
    CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(-1000, 0);

    _backgroundNode.position = ccpAdd(_backgroundNode.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, delta));

    for (CCSprite *background in _backgrounds) {
        if (([_backgroundNode convertToWorldSpace:background.position].x+background.contentSize.width/10) < -(background.contentSize.width)) {
            [_backgroundNode incrementOffset:ccp(background.contentSize.width*2,0) forChild:background];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add your texture to the texture cache only once, the CCSprite instance will not copy texture. It just stores a pointer to the texture and frame parameters(origin and size) to know, what part of texture to use(for example, if you have a big atlas with a lot of sprites packed in it).

actually, you may not to add your texture to the texture cache directly. it will be added to the texture cache in the CCSprite instance init method.

Comment: example? O_o 
CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: filePath];
after this line of code your texture will be loaded in the texture cache, the next sprite instance instance will find this texture in the texture cache and use it instead of creating texture copy

Comment: CCTexture2D* tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name]];
                    
CCSprite *fon_level_1 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex];
CCSprite *fon_level_2 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex];

Comment: or it extra and just twice CCSprite *fon_level_1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name]];?

Comment: you can use sprite with file. all will be ok with memory. and i prefer to avoid spriteWithTexture constructor. if you will pack your sprites in a big atlas (for example, 2048x2048 pixels), you will get the sprite with this whole huge texture